# How to put different columns into different arrays when reading a file in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, file, rows

I'm trying to put columns of a file into different arrays, the file is arranged like this:

```
0004    78  118
0014    79  118
0024    79  119
0034    77  119
0044    76  118
0054    76  117
0064    77  118
0074    75  119
0084    80  121
0094    81  122
```

So for this file I'd want to get 3 arrays for each column. Each column is separated by a tab character (or a space character, I can't tell what it translates to in code), and at the end of the row there's an end-line character. I have to read in multiple files at a time, so I have to put the data into their respective arrays and then the for loop loops again.
This is the code I have:

```
int BTsensors;
char filename2[50];
for (int i = 0; i < BTsensors; i++)
{
    sprintf(filename2, "BT_%d.txt", i + 1);
    FILE * fpointer;
    fpointer = fopen(filename2, "r");
    if (fpointer != 0)
    {
        //store the data in the arrays here

        fclose(fpointer);
    }
}
```

I tried using a loop where I stored in the data for the arrays in one array per row, and then made three other arrays and stored the first four elements of the large array in one of the smaller arrays, then skipped the element that contained the space, and did the same thing for the other two arrays. Syntactically, it was outrageous, and although I've been researching for hours I can't find any other way of doing it that's at my level, but I suspect it might have something to do with string manipulation.

Any assistance for this is deeply appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Suggest posting the "I tried using a loop where I stored in the data for the arrays in one array per row..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the fscanf function, which reads values according to a given format. For example, lines with three integers can be read and converted with

```
int val1[256], val2[256], val3[256];
...
if (fscanf (fpointer, " %d %d %d", &val1[i], &val2[i], &val3[i]) != 3) {
  /* Malformed line. */
} else {
  /* Line had three integers. */
}
```

In case you need to preserve the initial zeros in 0094 you could use the `%s` format for a string, along with a pointer to a string of suitable size.